# Location of modulation and multiplexing in a GSM network

Tags: gsm

My question is regarding the location of GSM channel access methods TDMA/FDMA.

Here is an illustration how voice is processed before reaching the base station on a tower:

[image]

It is not mentioning the multiplexing(TDMA/FDMA) part.

I have two questions:

1) Where is the modulation carried out? On the Base Station or before?

2) Where is the multiplexing(TDMA/FDMA) occurs? On the Base Station or before?

(Is base station just composed of antennas for transmission or also includes any of those processes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the things shown in green boxes are carried out on the mobile station. The final red arrow means "transmit from mobile antenna to base station".

Think about it: the entire point of the modulation is to be able to transmit!

Comment: Oh you are right thanks. But how abot TDMA FDMA multiplexing? Do they occur on the BS tower or some where else?

Comment: Again, the multiplexing is for the purpose of transmission. It's the "radio burst multiplexing" box on the diagram.

Comment: So TDMA and FDMA happend inside the phone? But dont you need many users data multiplex? Im confused

Comment: The phone transmits in its timeslot. Other phones transmit in different timeslots. The base station demultiplexes these.